# Integrating $\int_{0}^{2}\pi((\frac{2e^{x}}{e^{x}+1})^{2}-1)dx$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Integrating by using the substitution method, i have reached the following.

$[4\pi\ln(1+e^{x})-\frac{4\pi}{(1+e^{x})}-\pi x]_{0}^{2}$

$\Rightarrow [4\pi\ln(1+e^{2})-\frac{4\pi}{(1+e^{2})}-2\pi] - [4\pi\ln(2)-2\pi]$

Now using a calculator, I get the following figure rounded to one decimal value:
$\textbf{16.5}$

While the answer using an online tool as well as on exam paper is $\textbf{6.9}$

This is what I inserted in the calculator:
$(4\pi\ln(1+e^{2})-(\frac{4\pi}{(1+e^{2})})-2\pi)-(4\pi\ln(2)-2\pi)$

Which answer is right? How?

Comment: You should check your antiderivative by differentiating it.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: i got this result: $$4\,{\frac {\pi\, \left( {{\rm e}^{2}}\ln  \left( {{\rm e}^{2}}+1
 \right) -\ln  \left( 2 \right) {{\rm e}^{2}}+\ln  \left( {{\rm e}^{2}
}+1 \right) -{{\rm e}^{2}}-\ln  \left( 2 \right)  \right) }{{{\rm e}^{
2}}+1}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If we put $e^x=t $, it becomes

$$\int_1^{e^2}\pi\frac {4tdt}{(t+1)^2}-2\pi$$

$$=4\pi\int_1^{e^2}\frac {t+1-1}{(t+1)^2}dt-2\pi $$
$$=4\pi (\ln (e^2+1)-\ln (2)+\frac {1}{e^2+1}-\frac {1}{2})-2\pi $$

$$=4\pi \ln (\frac {e^2+1}{2})-\frac {4\pi e^2}{1+e^2}$$